# Framework to develop a large project in PHP

Tags: php, framework, mvc

Requirements:

1. Supported by a big community
2. lots of clones of well succeeded web sites already developed in open source
3. fast code and fast learning ( I know that these requirements can be contradictory)
4. it is still maintained (continuing development) and it is likely to be for years a good choice
5. MVC

I know that there are several ones, but my search did not answer my question.

**Codeigniter:** I used in the past and I love it. However people say that it is not going to be a good choice since it is not being developed anymore. Furthermore, some people suggest that I could work faster using yii, for instance. What I've found so far:

**Cake php:** it has a lot of clones of large sites. However, some people suggest that it is not scalable.

**Zend framework:** steep learning curve.

I know there are several more like Yii, Laravel, Sinfony, and others. Which would you recommend that matches my requirements?

Comment: "Crones"???????

Comment: Typo clones! Sorry! I was typing in an iPad defined in other language. Sometimes it makes very strange corrections!

Comment: You have multiple "crones" in your question.

Comment: Thank you again. For some reason, the same correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel is an open-source widely used PHP framework. The platform was intended for the development of web application by using MVC architectural pattern. Laravel is released under the MIT license. Therefore its source code is hosted on GitHub. It is a reliable PHP framework as it follows expressive and accurate language rules.

Why use Laravel?

- Laravel offers version control system that helps with simplified management of migrations.
- Modular packaging with composer based dependency manager.
- Support for Eloquent ORM, the advanced ActiveRecord implementation for working on DB.
- Support DBMS platforms like MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLServer.
- Offers features like blade templating engine.
- Support for artisan command along with sample codes line interface.
- Has great documentation.
- Laravel allows you to enforce constraints between multiple DBM objects by using an advanced query builder mechanism.
- The framework has an auto-loading feature, so you don't do manual maintenance and inclusion paths.
- The framework helps you to generate new tools with the help of a LOC container.

Comment: Another vote for Laravel. I've been using it for almost eight years now, and its star continues to rise. Thanks to the growth of its community, it's now difficult to find a PHP developer that is NOT familiar with it.